# How to cancel ongoing alarm in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm making an application in which I want to cancel an alarm(not set by my application) after few seconds.

What is the way to cancel alarm which may be set by any other application?

What I have is, notification posted on Android Notification Center when alarm triggers.

I read from android documentation that I need PendingIntent to cancel the triggered alarm. But how can I get PendingIntent in this case?

I noticed that I can get contentIntent from alarm notification,posted to the Android Notification Center. I tried to cancel alarm from this PendingIntent but did not succeed.

Any way to get PendingIntent of triggered alarm? Or/And to cancel alarm?

Comment: If you know the full information about its pendingIntent , then you can call the cancel method followed by its pending intent..

Comment: Then is there any way to get full information? And what do you mean by full information? What should I have to cancel the alarm?

Comment: Do you know the `package name` of the app which created the notification, along with `tag` and `id` parameters used to create the notification using [notify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify)  API?

Comment: To cancel the alarm you need to create the exact same PendingIntent which passed when setting the alarm. Basically the PI will be having an Intent to a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @ManishMulimani I can get tag and id parameters from notification posted in Android Notification Center...What to do after having those parameters?

Comment: @Alina you can use a global/application label context. Which will help to findout the context atleast.

Comment: @gnuanu Can you give an example? How can I do that in my case where I'm having only notification of the triggered alarm?

Comment: @RanjitPati Yes...that's true...but what about other parameters?

Comment: @ManishMulimani I know package name too..

Comment: @Alina just check my answer below. it may not solve your problem as i don't know where is your Alarm infos, but i'm sure you can resolve it now.

Answer (score 2):

This trick is a little bit old, but it saves many developers.

Suppose in ActivityOne we start an AlarmManager like:

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, OnServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5290, i, 0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, LOCAL_SERVICE_PERIOD, pi);
```

To cancel this AlarmManager in any other Activity/Broadcastreceiver/Service we have to remember some of its informations.

1: Context: The context used by the AlarmManager followed by its PendingIntent.

2: PendingIntent ID:   getBroadcast(context, **5290**, i, 0); .It makes the Pi unique which is mostly important.

So we have to save the PendingIntent id in a SharedPreference to confirm at the time of canceling.

Now the `Context` used by `AlarmManager` .

In same Activity( ActivityOne) we have to create a global Context which holds the original one. like:

```
//Define it globaly in ActivityOne
private static Context mContext;

//create a public static method which holds the current context and share
public static Context getActivityOneContext() {
    return ActivityOne.mContext;
}

//initialize it by assigning application context in onCreate() method
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

   //Or if this is a BroadCastReceiver ..use the current context and do same in onReceive()
   //OnBootReceiver.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
```

Now you can cancel the AlarmManager anywhere of the application..

```
       AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(ActivityOne.getActivityOneContext, OnServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent stopPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ActivityOne.getActivityOneContext, 5290, stopIntent, 0);
        mgr.cancel(stopPI);
```

Comment: I'm not setting alarm in my application and thus I can not have PI to cancel...All I have is triggered alarm's notification object...